# Image has a white space inside the BoxDecoration in flutter

Tags: user-interface, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm making a `DecorationBox` inside my `Container()`, I have added everything and the image is coming up fine but there is one problem, even after a lot of trials there is some white space which is always there inside the DecorationBox.

This is my code :

```
Container(
   height: 66.0,
   width: 66.0,
   padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
      border: Border.all(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
      image: DecorationImage(
         fit: BoxFit.cover,
         image: AssetImage("MY_URL")
      )
   )
)
```

The result which is coming is :

[image: Resultant picture]

I have tried giving removing padding by this code in my `Container()` :

```
Container(
   padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0)
)
```

I have followed this link for my problem solution, [Image is not taking up space in AlertBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50905591/flutter-how-to-remove-white-spaces-around-dialog-box) since it was the case of `AlerBox` hence I could use the elements named as `contentPadding` which is not available. Kindly help me with the same how to achieve my solution. Thanks

Here is my image, you can use it and let me know if it works for you.

[image: Image used for the problem]

Comment: Then there is one question arises @anmol.majhail, **I need to give out the height and width to the box**, and for this, I can only do via my container. However, I have used the same thing in my child, that is, `child: DecoratedBox()`, but it came like the above only.

Comment: Your image is a PNG with alpha (transparent) padding. You might want to crop it and save as new image,

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be the image you're using. I'm not sure if it's just a quirk of the upload, but the image you've linked has a border of empty space with a slight shadow to it. Try cropping the image and see if it helps

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ClipOval` widget and have child as the `Image.asset` directly. You can also do away with the `Container` and `BoxDecoration`.  Here's the updated and working code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
            child:
              ClipOval(
                child: Image.asset('assets/jnvVQ.png', height: 90.0,width: 90.0,),
              ),
            )
        );
  }
```

I passed the `height` and `width` to the Image directly instead of having a `Container` with those specs. And I see the image properly wrapped:

[image]

You can edit the height and width per your needs.

Comment: OP is welcome to correct me if I'm mistaken, but this doesn't produce the desired effect. The question has a cropped down version of the image with just the middle square of content, this has the entire image centred in a larger white square. You can see this if you wrap your ClipOval in a `Container(color: white)` and set the `Scaffold` to black - it's the same issue, but with more whitespace and no cropping happening at all

Comment: Alternatively changing `ClipOval` to `ClipRRect` and adding `fit: BoxFit.none` in your example does seem to give something pretty close to what OP is asking for, provided the image content is smaller than the height of the clipper and you don't need to stretch the image